# Ubuntu shows bluetooth keyboard as connected, but no input

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, 20.10

I've been using a Varmilo Bluetooth keyboard for a few days now and every time I turn of my laptop or it goes to sleep the keyboard connection will break.

Ubuntu will show that the a Bluetooth device is connected, but the keyboard's status light will still be blinking as if it was looking for a device to connect to. If I go into Bluetooth settings, remove the keyboard and connect it again, the pairing number will appear, but the keyboard connects regardless of the input - I can even close the window as soon as it appears and everything will be working just fine.

Anyone experienced anything similar?

```
Ubuntu: 21.04 groovy
Uname: Linux toronto 5.8.0-43-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 03:01:28 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Think about it you broke one end of the connection what would you expect to happen.

Comment: I've been using a ThinkPad bluetooth keyboard for almost a year before and never had any issues with it not reconnecting

Comment: I have the same thing you have with Bluetooth headphones.

Comment: So maybe this is something with the firmware on some bluetooth devices? I've used bluetooth headphones with my laptop and they always seemed to reconnect just fine